# How to avoid the sklearn import preprocessing statement giving error in python 3.5 version?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am getting the error as below while trying to execute "from sklearn import preprocessing".

ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'.

My python version is 3.5.

Can someone please help on this.

Regards,
Philip

Comment: `pip install scikit-learn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, I can only think maybe you don't have the library installed. Make sure you have NumPy and SciPy installed. Then make sure Scikit learn is actually installed. If you search how to install sklearn, a ton of results will show up instructing you how to do so. Basically,:

1. Install NumPy >= 1.6.1
2. Install SciPy >= 0.9
3. Install scikit-learn

Here is a link http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html.

If you are using pip, you can do `pip install numpy scipy`. Conda is similar, `conda install numpy` and `conda install scipy`.

I'm making a lot of assumptions here, so I'm not sure this is much help. Hopefully a good start though.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to install the 'scikit-learn' module. Here's a step-by-step explanation for resolving the error:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

You can verify that 'scikit-learn' is installed by running the following command:

```
python -m pip show scikit-learn
```